# Required Suggestion for filling German student Visa Application

Tags: visas, schengen-visas

I'm from India, got my acceptance in German university. In all my study documents and passport my father name is :RAMA, but while filling out Visa application there is column for Father's surname. Is it necessary to fill out the application with my father's surname or should I leave it blank.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the answer to a question, then answer it.
If you **do not** know the answer, leave it blank.

- **never** give an answer that **you** know to be false

In this case, **you know the answer**,  so answer it.

---

Since it **is possible** that a childs surname **is different** than their fathers surname, the question is (for them) relevent.

Whether it **makes sense or not** is **irrelevant**

- they want it, you give it

if not, they may refuse you the visa.

---

Based on the student visa application found here (german and english)

https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/de/newsroom/buergerservice-faq-kontakt/faq/08-studentenvisum/606218

At the end of the form it is stated: 
that the form must be completed to the best of their knowledge and belief

Any

- false
- refused
- **incomplete**

information can lead to refusal of a visa or if found out later expulsion.

---

In such matters it is wise (in my opinion) to always keep the old saying in mind:

- **Ours not to reason why, ours but to do and die**

https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/alfred_lord_tennyson_101361